# What does it mean for a "reference object of a file to be reassigned to another file"?

Tags: python, file

If I create a variable from a file `example = open(example_file)` and then read that file into a variable `example_read = example.read()` then I need to close the file later `example.close()`.

But if I read directly into the variable `example_read = open(example_file).read()` then I don't need to close it (i.e. it's not open). (Via [LPTHW](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex17.html))

Why is it already closed? I don't understand the following explanation - isn't the same thing being done whether it's done with an intermediate variable `example` or just directly to `example_read`?

> "Python automatically closes a file when the reference object of a file is reassigned to another file." - [TutorialsPoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `file` object created by the call to `open` is anonymous, in the sense that you don't create a reference to it. Once the call to `read` on that object completes and its return value is assigned to `example_read`, the object can be garbage collected, at which time the underlying file will be closed. However, you don't know exactly *when* that will happen, so the file could remain open for an unspecified period of time.

Better practice is to avoid such anonymous file objects and/or use a `with` statement to ensure that the file is closed when you are done with it.

```
with open(example_file) as fh:
    example_read = fh.read()
```

This guarantees that the file will be closed as soon as the `with` statement completes, even with an anonymous (although useless) object created by

```
with open(example_file):
    # Do something without the file object.
```

Comment: Can you explain why `example_read = open(example_file).read()` seems to leave an already closed file? Or is it just a coincidence (given that you say that the closing of a file after `read()` is "unspecified"? (I ask because it always tells me it isn't there if I do try to close it).

Comment: Most of the time, it will be closed. However, I'm not sure what you are trying to close. `example_read.close()` won't work, because `example_read` is the return value of the `read` method, not the `open` function. You don't have anything that you *can* call `close` on.

Comment: OK. what I didn't understand at first was that there is not point closing `example_file` since it isn't a file, its a string. What I had thought (wrongly) at first was that after `example_read = open(example_file).read()` I would have needed to close `example_file`.

Answer (score 0):

It means, for example

```
f = open( 'file1.txt', 'r' )
f = open( 'file2.txt', 'r' )
```

On the second line, the reference `f` is reassigned to another file (i.e. `file2.txt`).  So python will automatically close `file1.txt`.

N.B. your question is about re-opening the same file.  The answer is the same. I used two different files on purpose to make the explanation clearer.